# how to access function properly?

Tags: ios, swift, cell, navigationbar

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVkmp.png) i want to use this function which i have mention in custom subclass of uiview

this is messageviewcontroller file

```
import UIKit

    class MessageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var MessageData : NSMutableArray!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableviee: UITableView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            MessageData = NSMutableArray()
            MessageData.add(getMessageListData(image: "ProfileImageRound", profileName: "Silvestor Young", profileMessage: "Hi, I want to purchase your service, can you please provide it to me", Messagtime: "10 min ago"))
            
            MessageData.add(getMessageListData(image: "ProfileImageRound", profileName: "Welma Simpson", profileMessage: "How much is it cost to repeate it again", Messagtime: "22 min ago"))
            
            MessageData.add(getMessageListData(image: "ProfileImageRound", profileName: "Robert Doe", profileMessage: "It was really nice and calm", Messagtime: "1h ago"))
            
            MessageData.add(getMessageListData(image: "ProfileImageRound", profileName: "Steve Adams", profileMessage: "I need an extra piece of this can you provide it to me.", Messagtime: "1 h ago"))

            MessageData.add(getMessageListData(image: "ProfileImageRound", profileName: "Alizia Smith", profileMessage: "ok noted thanks", Messagtime: "3 h ago"))
            
            MessageData.add(getMessageListData(image: "ProfileImageRound", profileName: "JW Doe", profileMessage: "Thank you for your inquiry om this can you provide details for your so i can contact you", Messagtime: "3 h ago"))
            
            tableviee.register(UINib(nibName: "MessageMainCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessageMainCell")
            let messageBar = MessageBar.instanceFromNib() as! MessageBar
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: messageBar)
        }
        
        func getMessageListData(image: String, profileName: String, profileMessage: String, Messagtime: String) -> NSMutableDictionary{
            let data = NSMutableDictionary()
            data["image"] = image
            data["profileName"] = profileName
            data["profileMessage"] = profileMessage
            data["Messagetime"] = Messagtime
            return data
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return MessageData.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 100
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageMainCell", for: indexPath ) as! MessageMainCell
            if let setData = MessageData.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary{
                cell.setListdata(data: setData)
            }
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            let stroryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootVc = stroryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageDetailViewController") as! MessageDetailViewController
            let backImage = UIImage(named: "backArrowWhite")
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rootVc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

import UIKit

class MessageDetailbar: UIView {

```
@IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!



class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "MessageDetailbar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

func setBarData(data: NSDictionary){
    if let image = data["image"] as? String{
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    }

    if let Name = data["profileName"] as? String{
        name.text = Name
    }

    if let Time = data["Messagetime"] as? String{
        time.text = Time
    }
}
```

}

here i have used my customview in viewwillAppear

import UIKit

class MessageDetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

struct data{
    let time: String
    let message: String
    let date: String
    let type: String
}

struct section {
    let date: String
    var array = [data]()
}

let sectionArray = [
    section(date: "yesterday", array: [
            data(time: "3:30 PM", message: "I am looking for your service, can you please give more information on that.", date: "yesterday", type: "sender"),
            data(time: "3:40 PM", message: "Sure i am here to help you", date: "yesterday", type: "receiver")
        ]),
    section(date: "today", array: [
        data(time: "4:40 PM", message: "Ok, I wil contact you on your phone for that.", date: "today", type: "sender"),
        data(time: "5: 30 PM", message: "SO HERRE IS my contact number 9586670629", date: "today", type: "receiver"),
        data(time: "5: 30 PM", message: "OKAY I will call back you within 15 20 minitues", date: "today", type: "sender")
        ])
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "SenderCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SenderCell")
    self.tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "ReceiverCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReceiverCell")
    self.tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "customHeaderViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customHeaderViewCell")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let messageDetailBar = MessageDetailbar.instanceFromNib() as! MessageDetailbar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = messageDetailBar
}
```

}

extension MessageDetailViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionArray[section].array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].type == "sender"
        {
            let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SenderCell", for: indexPath) as! SenderCell
            cell.setData(reciverTime: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].time, reciverMsg: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].message)
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverCell", for: indexPath) as! ReceiverCell
            cell.setData(reciverTime: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].time, reciverMsg: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].message)
            return cell
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView()
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customHeaderViewCell") as! customHeaderViewCell
    if sectionArray[section].date == "yesterday"
        {
            headerCell.labelHeader.text = "yesterday"
        }
    else
        {
            headerCell.labelHeader.text = "today"
        }
    headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
    return headerView
    }
}
```

but i am not able to use it how can  use it proper way

i want to use custom navigation bar when on of the cell is selected [this] cell[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWQNS.png) to [this] navigation bar [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zqTd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your `MessageDetailViewController` or how you're passing the data from the selected index path, but assuming you have something like this:

```
class MessageDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    public var theData: NSDictionary!
```

you'll be passing the data in `didSelectRowAt` like this:

```
    let stroryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootVc = stroryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageDetailViewController") as! MessageDetailViewController
    
    // unwrap optional
    guard let setData = MessageData.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary else { return }
    
    // pass the data to the Detail controller
    rootVc.theData = setData
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rootVc, animated: true)
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad()` in `MessageDetailViewController`:

```
class MessageDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    public var theData: NSDictionary!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // whatever else you're doing to congfigure
        //  this controller
        
        // get an instance of MessageDetailbar
        let messageDetailBar = MessageDetailbar.instanceFromNib() as! MessageDetailbar
        // set the data
        messageDetailBar.setBarData(data: theData)
        // set it as the navigation bar's titleView
        self.navigationItem.titleView = messageDetailBar

    }

}
```

As a side note, override `intrinsicContentSize` in your `MessageDetailbar` class so it will fill the available horizontal space:

```
class MessageDetailbar: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "MessageDetailbar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
    
    func setBarData(data: NSDictionary){
        if let image = data["image"] as? String{
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
        }
        
        if let Name = data["profileName"] as? String{
            name.text = Name
        }
        
        if let Time = data["Messagetime"] as? String{
            time.text = Time
        }
    }

    // add this
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize
    }

}
```

Comment: oh that worked perftectly thank you so much DonMag i have one more question what if i use this in viewWillAppear and second question is that funtion which we used in custom view?

Comment: @helibhadeshiya - not sure what you're asking... why would you want to use it in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad()`? And I don't know what you mean with your second question.

Comment: yes i want to use in what is diffrence between viewDidLoad() and viewWillAppear ? the second question is that use told me to add intrinsicContentSize : CGSize ... what does it mean ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329893/how-to-give-autoresize-constrain. can you  be a solver these for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it right, you are trying to reach to custom view that is somehow used as a navigationBar. You want to update that custom view according to cell selected in tableview.

There are couple of ways to do that but you can't directly access that setBarData function if you don't have any reference in your viewController.

Can you show us where you use that MessageDetailbar in your code?

Comment: yes you understood well that i am trying to reach custom view used as navigation bar i want to use setBarData(data: NSDictionary) (which is defined in custom view) in didSelectRowAt

Comment: @helibhadeshiya can you share where you initialize your customview and define in your code? If it's somewhere in your custom navigation controller, you can extend your custom navigation controller class to update navigation bar.